# Buildrequiring a subpackage by another subpackage?

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build an RPM of Google's protobuf, including the protobuf-python subpackage. Now, this is no problem until i want to build the python subpackage with `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp python setup.py build`. This requires the protobuf header files and lib provided by the protobuf-devel package, which is built from the same .spec and source tarball.

The question is, is it somehow possible to build the (-python) subpackge in such scenario using a single .spec & tarball, or must i create a separate spec?

Here's the [.src.rpm](http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/epel/beta/7/SRPMS/protobuf-2.5.0-6.el7.src.rpm) if anyone is curious. All i did was to prepend the `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp` to `python setup.py build` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sub-package you are building depends on other header file/etc. data from the sources used for other parts of that specfile then I don't think you want (or need) a `BuildRequires` on that `-devel` package and including it would be wrong.

You already have (and are guaranteed to have) the header files somewhere locally (possibly in your current directory already) when your sub-package is going to be built (which is all a `BuildRequires` is supposed to guarantee for you).